# C++ use a class in a class (in a class) and call their functions

Tags: c++, class

I have the following problem: I wanted to redo a project from good old `C` to `C++` and make everything `class(y) :)` and keep it scalable from the beginning.

It is a simulation of cells (being part of a swarm) on a grid, so I decided the following structure:

```
class Simulation has an instance of
class Grid       has an instance of
class Swarm      has an instance of
class Cell
```

I defined the classes in separate header files. Then I need, of course, to be able to call functions in grid, swarm and cell as well. I wanted to do it straight forward:

```
Simulation mysim;
mysim.get_grid(0).any_function_here();
```

with the grid as return parameter

```
Grid Sim::get_grid(int grid_no)
{
    std::cout << "sim.get_grid(" << grid_no << ") called." << std::endl;
    if (grid_no <= amount_of_grids)
        return this->test;//##//this->gridlist[grid_no];
    else
        std::cout << "you have not created this grid number yet" << std::endl;

    Grid dummy;
    return dummy;
}
```

It calls the function and works as long as no changes in the grid are made. These seem to be lost in space. Probably a pointer error, but I cannot find an error, since exactly the same code is working for the `Simulation` class...

More source:

```
int Grid::create_swarm(std::string name)
{
    Swarm new_swarm;
    new_swarm.set_name("Protoswarm");
    swarmlist.push_back(new_swarm);
    this->amount_of_swarms ++;
    std::cout << "amount_of_swarms = " << amount_of_swarms << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Swarm Grid::get_swarm(int swarm_no)
{
    std::cout << "grid.get_swarm(" << swarm_no << ") called." << std::endl;
    if (swarm_no <= amount_of_swarms)
        return swarmlist[swarm_no];
    else
        std::cout << "oh oh - you have not this swarm in here..." << std::endl;

    Swarm dummy;
    return dummy;
}
```

I can call the `create_swarm` function as often as I want, but the swarms do never appear and the counter does not raise in that grid, just temporarily as long as the funtion is in there. Am I missing something? Is it really just a pointer error? Why does this code work if I call it like this:

```
Grid newgrid;
newgrid.create_swarm();
```

A quickly c&p'ed MWE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Sim
{
    public:
        Sim();
        virtual ~Sim();

        Grid get_grid(int grid_no);

    protected:

    private:
        std::vector<Grid> gridlist;
        int amount_of_grids = -1;
};


class Grid
{
    public:
        Grid();
        virtual ~Grid();

        int set_size(int x, int y);
        int create_swarm(std::string name);
        Swarm get_swarm(int swarm_no);
        void print_swarms();

    protected:

    private:
        std::vector<Swarm> swarmlist;
        int amount_of_swarms = -1;
        /*static const*/ int size_x;
        /*static const*/ int size_y;
        std::vector<std::vector<Field>> fields;
        std::string gridname;
};

Grid Sim::get_grid(int grid_no)
{
    std::cout << "sim.get_grid(" << grid_no << ") called." << std::endl;
    if (grid_no <= amount_of_grids)
        return this->gridlist[grid_no];
    else
        std::cout << "you have not created this grid number yet" << std::endl;

    Grid dummy;
    return dummy;
}

int Grid::create_swarm(std::string name)
{
    Swarm new_swarm;
    new_swarm.set_name("Protoswarm");
    swarmlist.push_back(new_swarm);
    this->amount_of_swarms ++;
    std::cout << "amount_of_swarms = " << amount_of_swarms << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Swarm Grid::get_swarm(int swarm_no)
{
    std::cout << "grid.get_swarm(" << swarm_no << ") called." << std::endl;
    if (swarm_no <= amount_of_swarms)
        return swarmlist[swarm_no];
    else
        std::cout << "oh oh - you have not this swarm in here..." << std::endl;

    Swarm dummy;
    return dummy;
}


using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Sim mysim;
    mysim.create_grid();
    mysim.get_grid(0).create_swarm("Alpha-Swarm");
    mysim.get_grid(0).create_swarm("Betaa-Swarm"); //doesn't work

    Grid newgrid;
    newgrid.create_swarm("Gamma-Swarm");
    newgrid.create_swarm("Delta-Swarm"); // works, but is not needed.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [MCVE] if possible.

Comment: Returning a class in C++ is exactly like returning a struct in "good old" C; it creates a copy.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it is hard to tell but it looks like the problem is you are not returning references to the data in the vector.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, ok - you are right, thanks! But was I too long out of business o.o Why is the other "direct" example working then?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it, was a long day, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Grid Sim::get_grid(int grid_no) {...}
```

You are returning by value, not by reference. That means that what you are returning is a **copy** of your actual member. In your case, however, you want to be returning by reference in order to be able to make changes to the original object. Your code would become

```
Grid& Sim::get_grid(int grid_no) {...}
```

Keep in mind, however, that you will not be able to return any temporaries that way (such as your `dummy` Grid), so you will need to change your methods to circumvent this issue. If you do not want to do this, you could still return a pointer, although this would change the syntax a little.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_grid` and `get_swarm` methods return copies of original array items. You should return reference (or a pointer) to `Grid` or `Swarm` instead.